# How to generate Allure Report programmatically - after end of test suite

Tags: java, testing, automated-tests, allure

How to generate Allure report from Java code?
Right now I'm using terminal together with allure-comandline as  `allure generate build/allure-results --clean`
I'd like to automatically generate it after end of test suite. I did some research and found this https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-generator but unfortunately this doesn't work or I don't know how to use it properly.
Also tried this:

```
new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("build/allure-report")).unpackFace(); 
new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("build/allure-report")).processResults(new File("build/allure-results"));
```

Anyone have working code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using Maven/Gradle to run tests. Why not use Maven/Gradle plugin to generate reports?

[Allure Maven](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_maven_6) /
[Allure Gradle](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_gradle_5)

Answer (score 0):

```
new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("build/allure-report")).unpackFace(); 
new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("build/allure-report")).processResults(new File("build/allure-results"));
```

If above code you written actually build report, then you can use it in something like this.

```
// This will run only once, just before program is exiting
static {
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
    new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("build/allure-report")).unpackFace(); 
    new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("build/allure-report")).processResults(new File("build/allure-results"));
    }));
}
```

Add above code to your base test class (if you don't have base test class, just add it to the existing test class). It will be executed after all tests ran.

Comment: no, `new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("build/allure-report")).unpackFace(); 
new AllureReportBuilder("1.5.4", new File("build/allure-report")).processResults(new File("build/allure-results"));` doesn't work at all. That's the problem ;) not how to execute code, but thanks for replay ;)